# Ember.js transition to create new record, not update last saved record

Tags: ember.js

I'm beginning learning ember.js by recreating a little toy app that I had built in Rails.

I have a form to creates a new record, which after save should redirect to the same form to create the next new record.

I have the following ember.js code:

```
App.WordsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(actions:
  submit: (word) ->
    word.save()
    @transitionToRoute "words.new"
    return
)
```

Instead of the behavior I am expecting, which would be a form for a new record, after the first save, I'm getting rerouted to a form that *updates* the created record.

I'm sure there's a very simple way to force a new record to be reloaded, after saving the current record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

transitioning to a route that's already in the view, won't hit the model hook again (since it's assumed you already have the model) and won't do much, since that model/view is already on the page.

Your code probably looks like this:

```
App.WordsNewRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.store.create('word');
  }
});
```

You'll need to manually swap out the model.  And transitioning isn't necessary, if you are already on the route.

```
App.WordsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(actions:
  submit: (word) ->
    word.save()
    @set 'model', store.createRecord('word')
    return
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I think the third line of controller needs a comma after @set 'model'? I modified my code to match yours but I am still seeing the same behavior: after the first record, the form becomes an update action....

Comment: Hah, thanks, I guessed on the coffee script, can you show a basic example on emberjs.jsbin.com

Comment: Had to heavily modify to get this sort of working, but this is the basic idea: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nagex/1/edit?html,css,js,console. In my actual app, save is working the first time; each subsequent attempt is trying to update instead of create new.

Comment: Actually, I tinkered a bit further with your code and got it working! I just had to modify this line:

    @set 'model', @store.createRecord('word')

Thanks so much for your help!